# Can a PLC connect via MQTT without a broker?

Tags: mqtt, plc, broker

I have to connect a device that sends the information via MQTT, and then I have to use my PLC to do so. I already did it using a virtual broker on a Raspberry Pi, but I need a more reliable solution because this is for a industrial job. Also it will be ideal to be local (that's why we try it out with a Raspberry Pi) so if you know some way to bypass the broker or can recommend me some sort of device to buy that will help me to do so I'll be extremely thankful. My PLC is a 5069-L306ER CompactLogix 5380.

I already tried all the conventional ways. My last idea its to use a server in the plant to work has a broker, but it's not the ideal.

Comment: The way I understand MQTT, if you are a Client (Publisher or Subscriber), you must connect to a Broker.  You can't be an MQTT Client without connecting to a Broker.

Comment: Some industrial HMIs have an internal MQTT Broker, see Weintek's cMT lines for example. If I'm not mistaken, there are PLCs with Broker too, take a look at Wago PLCs. Another robust option is to use an industrial PC, but then the problem will be the cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. You can't do MQTT without a server/broker.

As noted in both version [3.1.1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html) and [5](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html) of the MQTT specification:

> MQTT is a **Client Server** publish/subscribe messaging transport protocol. (emphasis mine)

In other words, you *must* have a server. MQTT doesn't support peer-to-peer communication.

Comment: Thank you, i thought it would be like that, do you know any kind of device (not Raspberry or a PC) that i  may use as a local Broker?

Comment: Anything with a TCP/IP stack can run a broker (I know of a air purifier/fan that runs it's own broker). But what exact problem are you trying to solve by saying not a PC? What makes you think anything else will be more reliable? (p.s. hardware recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow)

Comment: i was trying some kind of brokerless communication, but my devices were incompatible, so now i´m trying to use an industrial PC with node-red as intermediary, but i still have some problems making the connection between the Node-Red and the PLC